# How to refer wwwroot path files in web.config - Azure App service

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, .net-4.5

I deployed .Net web api in Azure App service. My Log folder located in WWWROOT Folder. 
My Folder structure like below

```
↓WWWROOT
 >bin
 ↓Logs
  >TraceLog.log 
Web.Config
```

**I want to refer**

> TraceLog.log

**path in web.config.**

I tried following ways

```
fileName="%home%\site\wwwroot\Logs\TraceLog.log" 
fileName="C:\DWASFiles\Sites\[your websitnmame]\site\wwwroot\Logs\TraceLog.log"
fileName="C:\DWASFiles\Sites\[your-websitename]\VirtualDirectory0\Logs\TraceLog.log"
fileName="~\Logs\TraceLog.log"
fileName="\Logs\TraceLog.log"
```

but getting this error
[image]

Comment: Did you try opening the file manual using .NET API instead of going through the special API? This will help isolate.

Answer (score 1):

As Thiago Custodio and Jeff mentioned that we could use  code easily do that. In your case, please have a try to use the following code.

```
string traceLogPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME") + @"\site\wwwroot\logs\TraceLog.log";
```

As [Azure WebApp is sanbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox), **d:\home** is available for the sandbox with read/write access.File structure on azure please refer to this [document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/File-structure-on-azure).

> **Home directory access (d:\home)**
>
> Every Azure Web App has a home directory stored/backed by Azure Storage. This network share is where applications store their content. This directory is available for the sandbox with read/write access.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use the local storage which the intent is to provide temporary file storage for IIS and web application frameworks, I would recommend you to write your logs on Azure Storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. They designed it so it's not readinly available. Neither the AppDomain.BaseDirectory or the Environment.CurrentDirectory points there...but you can find it under the %HOME% environment variable...but you must call ExpandEnvironmentVariables in code to refer to the path or specify the full path

You should note that your web.config is basically ignored since the app service runtime has its own web.config...so any references to paths must be in your code, not your web.config